# Scan log for errors and email error lines

Tags: php, email, logging, error-handling

I want a cron job to scan the logs on a daily basis and report all the err lines via email. I can handle PHP but I am new to Unix. Is there any fast Unix command that can write the output to another file, which I can email using another job?

Answer (score 0):

Sure,

You have to redirect the STDOUT and STDERR to a file...

Please see the following crontab example!

```
* * * * * root script.php 2>&1 /tmp/script-output.log | mail -s 'Subject' to@test.com
```

Byeee!

Comment: Or maybe you should have a look the php functions: set_error_handler and mail.

Comment: Is this a viable solution? 1) Create a "auto_prepend.php" file in the web root and add this:

<?php
register_shutdown_function('error_alert');

function error_alert()
{
        if(is_null($e = error_get_last()) === false)
        {
                mail('your.email@example.com', 'Error from auto_prepend', print_r($e, true));
        }
}
?>

2) Then add this "php_value auto_prepend_file /www/auto_prepend.php" to your .htaccess file in the web root.
--- From: php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php

Comment: Since this is a web-app on shared hosting, I may not have access to ROOT.. will it work without that? What is script.php doing?